# Listing database values according to the selected filter in dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, database, filtering

How do I filter dropdown options to list my table entries?

HTML filter example:

```
<form action="filter.php" method="post">
  <select name="filter">
    <option>FILTER:</option>
    <option value="alphabetical">ASC</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Basic MySQL select:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name
```

Basic HTML that lists values:

```
echo '<h1>'.$name.'</h1>
      <h1>'.$date.'</h1>';
```

The second filter (date) should do a SELECT that lists all the entries with ASC dates. The second first one (alphabetical) should do a SELECT that lists all the name's entries by ASC only.

Any idea of how the MySQL SELECT would work in that case?

Comment: get $_POST['filter'] value in your filter.php, use it to create a switch on your php script and create a different query for each parameter, or concat the "ORDER BY x" statement to a simple query like SELECT * FROM table.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that without redirecting to filter.php?

Comment: Yes, by using javascript/jquery ajax request, that way you can perform a filter on the server side and return the data to your client withouth performing any redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**html:**

```
<select name="filter" onchange="filter(this.value)">
  <option>FILTER:</option>
  <option value="alphabetical">ASC</option> 
  <option value="date">Date</option> 
</select>
<div id="results"></div>// store the results here
```

**Jquery:**

```
function filter(item){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "filter.php",
data: { value: item},
success:function(data){
  $("#results").html(data);
}
});
}
```

**filter.php:**

```
include "connection.php";  //database connection
$fieldname = $_POST['value'];
 if($fieldname=="alphabetical"){
  // if you choose first option
  $query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC"); 
  // echo the results
  }else{
  // if you choose second option
  $query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC");
  // echo the results
}
```

**Note:** Do not forget to include jquery library.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, Joke. When I select an option, like "alphabetical", nothing changes on my listing, I think this is because there's no "action". I will edit the code.

Comment: I suggest you to use ajax here instead of `form` which displays message without refreshing the page..

Comment: I used this: <select name="filer" onChange="$('#myForm').submit();">
Now the dropdown filter is respecting my select, but I'm getting mysqli errors: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Thankyou again, Joke. Do I need to put the SELECT inside a form?

Comment: Actually, the select option doens't affect my listing. :( But the php code is working great.

Comment: I added the jQuery in my header: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/filter.js"></script>

Comment: alert your response and tell me what does it display..Do this `alert(data);` after your success function.

Comment: It returns all my HTML page content when I select an option.

Comment: what did you echo in your php page??

Comment: I've put my variables inside the #results div.

Comment: Hey, I just figured out: I needed to include my array in a different file. Thankyou, Joke! Couldn't get it done without your help.

Answer (score 0):

These should work, assuming name and date are the field names in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this,

HTML:

```
<form action="filter.php" method="post">
  <select name="filter">
    <option>FILTER:</option>
    <option value="alphabetical">ASC</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    switch($_POST['filter']){
        case "alphabetical":
           $field = "name";
           break 1;
        case "date":
           $field = "date";
           break 1;
    }

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ? ASC");
 $stmt->bind_params("s",$field);
 $stmt->execute();

 //ETC
?>
```