# listing database values for select and processing form php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have used the following post to create a filtered dropdown list from my database table, its working fine.

[Listing database values according to the selected filter in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430211/listing-database-values-according-to-the-selected-filter-in-dropdown)

Before I edit with ajax, my process.php was working perfect without any problems and even after I have made my changes the filtering with select option is working fine.

codes from the above post which the answer was accepted.
**html**

```
<select name="filter" onchange="filter(this.value)">
  <option>FILTER:</option>
  <option value="alphabetical">ASC</option> 
  <option value="date">Date</option> 
</select>
<div id="results"></div>// store the results here
```

Jquery:

```
function filter(item){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "filter.php",
        data: {value: item},
        success: function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
      });
}
```

filter.php:

```
include "connection.php";  //database connection
$fieldname = $_POST['value'];
if($fieldname == "alphabetical"){
  // if you choose first option
  $query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC"); 
  // echo the results
  }else{
  // if you choose second option
  $query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC");
  // echo the results
}
```

My form looks like this

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label>Code</label><input type="text" name="code" />
    <label>Course</label>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now my problem is when I submit my form its sending the values to filter.php not process.php

Please, how do i rectify this problem?
Thanks

as per user1406062's request from my network console
[web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy4S6.jpg)

My process.php

```
include("../include/session.php");

class UserProcess
{
   /* Class constructor */
   function UserProcess(){
      global $session;
      if(!$session->isUser()){
         header("Location: ../index.php");
         return;
      }
      /* Student submit forms to register course */
      if(isset($_POST['subreg'])){
         $this->procReg();
      }
      else if(isset($_POST['subrem'])){
         $this->procRem();
      }
      else{
         header("Location: ../index.php");
      }
   }

   function procReg(){
      global $session, $form;
      $_POST = $session->cleanInput($_POST);
      $retval = $session->RegU($_POST['courseid'], $_POST['user']);
      /* Add Successful */
      if($retval == 0){
         $_SESSION['addsuccess'] = true;
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
      }
      /* Error found with form */
      else if($retval == 1){
         $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
      }
      /* Add failed */
      else if($retval == 2){
         $_SESSION['addsuccess'] = false;
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
      }
   }
$userprocess = new UserProcess;
```

Comment: if you use a web developer console, just the one available in Chrome, Safari or FireFox, can you include a snapshot of the network tab?

Comment: I have updated my question with the snapshot

Comment: thanks for adding the snapshot. Looking at the network tab, I can see status 302, which means redirected request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 Can you show the code in `process.php`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the code from process.php. It's working fine without the ajax.

Comment: I would suggest you avoid using `$_POST`, `$_GET` and other server specific variables inside classes. This makes unit testing them easier. Anyhow, can you change all the `header(...)` commands to `die(...)`? this will show you which part has been executed before a redirect is made.

Comment: this is what I am getting after making all headers to die, "Location: /mysite/include/filter.php"

Comment: You should now see that `process.php` redirects the request to `filter.php`. Can you do this last debugging step. Change every `header("Location: ...")` to `die("1.Location:...")` and `die("2.Location:...")` and `die("3.Location:...")` ... so you would know exactly which line of code has been invoked and why. Then try to figure out why `process.php` redirects the request to `filter.php`

Comment: yes I found which header redirecting, it is when $retval == 0, inside if statement. Its actually from my session class which stores the last url as refferer.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight on debugging redirection, user1406062. I have fixed my process.php with the correct redirection and its now working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your JavaScript function you have hard-coded URL:

```
function filter(item){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    **url: "filter.php",**
    data: {value: item},
    success: function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
    }
  });
```

}

and you are not using the form Action URL... Just change filtert.php to process.php

Comment: I have already fixed the problem and it was not the Ajax which caused the error. It was one of the redirection from my process.php. if you check my code snippets you will find that I have filter.php and process.php with separate functions.